# "The Torah shall be my profession" or "my faith"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilla, history, shacharis-morning-prayer, text

Following Modeh Ani in [the Siddur](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/sidurim/sfarad/hol/shaharit.asp), some recite a number of sentences (some of which are verses from the Torah):

> תּורָה צִוָּה לָנוּ משֶׁה מורָשָׁה קְהִלַּת יַעֲקב. שְׁמַע בְּנִי מוּסַר אָבִיךָ וְאַל תִּטּושׁ תּורַת אִמֶּךָ. **תּורָה תְּהֵא אֱמוּנָתִי. וְאֵל שַׁדַּי בְּעֶזְרָתִי.** וְאַתֶּם הַדְּבֵקִים בַּה' אֱלהֵיכֶם חַיִּים כֻּלְּכֶם הַיּום. לִישׁוּעָתְךָ קִוִּיתִי ה':

The middle sentence (bolded above) is translated as ([NJOP, Lesson 30](https://njop.org/wp-content/uploads-post-launch/2011/05/Reishith-Binah-Single-Pages.pdf)):

> The Torah shall be my faith and the Almighty my help

I have heard that it should be read as תּורָה תְּהֵא אוּמָנוּתִי - "Torah should be my craft/profession".

What is the original source of this phrase, which version does it support, and how/when might this have changed?
**I'm looking for research beyond the comments of the Yalkut Yosef in Hashkamat Haboker (note 1:11) which notes that the Rokeach (Shavuot, 296) writes it as "craft/profession" as opposed to "faith", and argues in favor of that reading.**

Comment: Emunati is strange because Tora is not an emuna. But torato umnuto is known

Comment: @kouty agreed. But every modern-day version that I have seen says that.